# Is there any benefit in using protocol buffers if I'm transferring binary payloads?

Tags: rest, protocol-buffers

I'm working on designing a micro-service that enable users to upload files and download files. Something like AWS S3 or swift.

I was wondering if my API payloads will be in binary anyway, is there any benefits in using Protocol Buffers ?

Comment: The short answer is no. The primary feature of protocol buffers is to generate native serializable classes from an interface. You may find secondary features of use, but it’s probably best to look elsewhere for them if you won’t be using the main feature.

Comment: Of course, if you wanted to exchange meta-data about the files through a well-defined interface, protocol buffers would be perfect

Comment: If *all* you have is something like `message MyFile { bytes payload = 1; }`: then, no; is your scenario more complex than that?

Comment: Thanks zzxyz and Marc Gravell . I was thinking in using request/response headers for sending meta-data (since they are simple and limited). My scenarios are basic CRUD oerations around objects and their containers (like folders)

Comment: There'd be a few reasons to use protocol buffers in that scenario, vs http headers, JSON, XML, etc.  1)  High performance..like, if you were exchanging metadata about files more often than actually exchanging files, it could significantly cut bandwidth.  2)  Interaction with clients without access to JSON/XML/http libraries.  3) Far more powerful than http headers for complex data exchange.  (Directory listings with CRCS, sizes, timestamps, etc...I would not use headers for)